# Passing int values directly to a function which expects a "const int&" as an argument results in weird behaviour

Tags: c++

My goal is to pass any kind of value by const reference. In this example I will refer to the int datatype (I am aware that passing the int value directly may be faster).

I am wondering about the following behavior and can't find any explanation for this.

```
#include <iostream>

void func(const int& val){

    std::cout << &val << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    func(21);
    func(22);
}
```

Output of the program above is the following:

```
0x7fffffffe214
0x7fffffffe214
```

I pass the values by const int& and although the values 21 and 22 are completely different, there seems to have the same memory address.

On the other hand this problem does not occur if i don't pass the int values directly into the function but storing them first in a separate variable like so:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(const int& val){

    std::cout << &val << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    const int& t = 21;
    const int& t2 = 22;
    func(t);
    func(t2);
}
```

Now the result is how i would expect it (two different memory addresses):

```
0x7fffffffe200
0x7fffffffe204
```

Can some explain what is going on here and may give me a hint for further reading?
I would very appreciate this!

**Edit:**
Thank you all for your comments. That seems logic. I encountered this "Problem" when i tried to build my own Stack data structure (with templates). My push function receives a `const T&` where T is the generic typename. Because i internally store an pointer to that address of that reference variable that leads to a Problem when the user of my data structure only pass the number and not a variable.
If a am not wrong the `push_back` function of `std::vector` class receives a `const T&` too. But I cannot observe the explained behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func(const int& val){

    std::cout << &val << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        func(vec.at(i));
}
```

Here a got the output:

```
0x5631dc47ded0
0x5631dc47ded4
```

Is that randomness or should you never pass direct values to functions which receives references?
Should i avoid to pass direct values to data structure at all?

**Edit (2):**
Thank you all for your comments and for reopening this question again! With your help I came across lvalues and rvalues. This seems to be what I am looking for. So when building a data structure would it make sense to overload the function that adds new object to the data structure to distinguish between lvalues and rvalues, where for lvalues simply store their reference and rvalues are assigned a memory location, i.e. an lvalue, by the function? If this value is queried by the user, if I understand correctly, you could then return either the reference to the original lvalue, or a reference to the lvalue where the rvalue was stored when it was passed to the data structure. Would that make sense and be good code? How does this work in classes like std::vector?

Comment: Why is it a "problem"?

Comment: There is nothing preventing two different values from occupying the same memory *at different times*. Note that the scope of function arguments at the first example is limited to function invocation expression while at the second example both values exist in the same scope (the `main` function).

Comment: So you mean the "variable" (respectively the int value) which i have passed directly  and which memory address is printed by the function lives only in that one line and will be destroyed immediately so the other variable in the next line can occupy this memory location on the stack?

Comment: `func(21);` has to create a temporary so it can pass a reference to it, which is then destroyed at the end of the full-expression (`;`). `func(22);` also has to materialise a temporary etc.  What you are observing is just the compiler re-using the stack address for two the temporaries.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have edited my question to better frame this information.  Perhaps you can also give me valuable advice or explanations in this regard?

Comment: There is no typo or error in this question and can be easily reproduced. It seems to me this is something others could wonder about as well. This should have an answer formed from Richards comment

Comment: *"Because i internally store an pointer to that address of that reference variable"* The pointer will become dangling, since the temporary `int` passed to the function will die soon after the function returns. You getting the same or different pointers doesn't change anything.

Comment: Coincidentally, the problem in your code is storing pointers from a source you cannot account for, using an API that doesn't even hint at pointer being stored. That's a major flaw to be fixed. It's wrong to conclude that passing temporaries is therefore always evil just because we wrote buggy code.